# Adding a checkbox column shows error : "Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0"

Tags: javascript, datatables

I need to add a new column to show a checkbox for further table operations, and i'm constantly getting the "Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0.”

Previously, the datatable's code was like this (And it worked with no errors) :

```js
    tabla = $('#table').DataTable({
            /** Default Configuration, it is read from a file but i'll show some of the values in case it is needed for a better understanding of the problem  **/
            destroy: true,
            pagingType : "full_numbers",
            paging : true,
            lengthChange : true,
            lengthMenu : /*Array*/,
            pageLength : 25,
            serverSide : true,
            ordering : false,
            searching : true,
            processing : true,
            deferRender : true,
            fnDrawCallback : configDefectoDatatables.fnDrawCallback,
            /** AJAX **/
            ajax : {
                beforeSend: beforeSend,
                url : urlAjax,
                type : "POST",
                timeout : 50000,
                error : errorNotificationFunction
            },
            /** Column Definition **/
            columns : [ {
                class : "idClass",
                data : "id",
                defaultContent : "",
                targets : 0
            }, {
                class : "requestClass",
                data : "request",
                defaultContent : "",
                targets : 1
            },
           /**Some other columns with the same format **/
           {...}]
```

My attempt was creating a new `<th>` before the others to the HTML file, and adding the following column as the new '0' (And moving the other column's targets one position upwards)

This does indeed show the checkbox on every row, and enables the multiple selection feature, but it still shows the mentioned error

```js
{
    orderable: false,
    className: 'select-checkbox',
    targets:   0
}
```

And also, the required select property as follows

```js
select: {
            style:    'multi',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        }
```

I was trying some random nonsense and found that adding a `data : null` made the error disappear, but added a new problem (it shows an `[Object object]` and the checkbox on top of it)

```js
{
    orderable: false,
    data : null,
    className: 'select-checkbox',
    targets:   0
}
```

I know it may (and probably will) be a simple problem due to my lack of knowledge of the technology but i'm not getting any solution by myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so, this may not be the best solution, but simply setting the column like this fixed the error

```
{
    data : null,
    defaultContent : "",
    className : 'select-checkbox',
    targets : 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
{
defaultContent: "",
orderable: false,
targets: 0,
checkboxes: {
  selectRow: true
}                                           
},
```

this worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).